# "}" was unexpected at this time error in quarkus

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, smallrye

i created a boilerplate project by **Quarkus starter** and **quarkus-smallrye-reactive-messaging-amqp** extension and when i run

```
./mvnw quarkus:dev
```

i get **"}" was unexpected at this time** error.

i run the app once without config as boilerplate was and once with below configs

```
amqp-username=root
amqp-password=root
mp.messaging.outgoing.price.connector=smallrye-amqp
mp.messaging.outgoing.price.address=prices
mp.messaging.outgoing.price.durable=true
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.connector=smallrye-amqp
mp.messaging.incoming.prices.durable=true
```

but got same error in both conditions

Comment: If you have a reproducible set of steps or if you can post your config it would be easier to help you.  It looks like one of your config files is probably broken

Comment: @Deadron tnx, i added configs

Comment: Given the error it really looks like a problem in a JSON or Javascript file.  It could also be an issue in your message parsing but its not clear if you app is failing on startup or during execution